# How to prove that the ground state of the Hubbard model is not a Slater determinant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, quantum-information

Of course it is expected. But how to prove it analytically?

Slater determinant is mentioned in almost every quantum mechanics textbook. But it is necessary to warn the undergraduate students that not every fermionic wave function is a Slater determinant.

So is there any model whose ground state can be easily and rigorously shown to be not a Slater determinant?

I had this problem since my paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1848, in which we considered the best Slater approximation of a fermionic wave function.

Comment: Write the state, apply the Hamiltonian, and you'll find that it is not an eigenstate. The easiest way would be to use second quantification.

Comment: no, the state is not explicitly known.

Comment: Then I might not get what you mean by Slater determinant: isn't it just build from the localized one-body wave-function? Or do you just mean that in general, one cannot write the ground-state of an interacting system cannot be written in terms of the (antisymmetrized) product of a possibly complicated one-body wavefunction ?

Comment: You get it. The latter.

Comment: In that case, can't you prove that by induction? Show that it does not work for 2 particles, then show that if it does not work for n, it can't work for n+1.

Comment: I did not try this way. I do not think that this will be an effective approach.

Comment: In that case, I let you figure out a better approach yourself.